# JSON file writing corruption with fs module

Tags: json, discord.js, fs, writefile

Since somes weeks, I am trying to create an XP System with Discord.js V13 but when I write on a JSON file with fs module new datas, I'm getting an issue in the JSON file like:

```
{
  "status" : {
    "server-id": "on"
  }
}}
```

Somes extra brackets and getting:
**JSON unexpected end**

I'm using this code to write in JSON files:

```
​fs​.​writeFile​(​"./DataBase/xp-system.json"​,​ ​JSON​.​stringify​(​xp_system​,​ ​null​,​ ​4​)​,​ ​(​err​)​ ​=>​ ​{ 
    ​if​ ​(​err​)​ ​console​.​error​(​)​;
​}​)​;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not familiar with the objects in the question, but a thought occurred. Is the `writeFile` replacing the file, or just replacing the *contents* of the file? I could see a case where you earlier had written `: "off"` to your file, and then overwrite the contents and now have `: "on"`, one character less. This would leave the final bracket from the previous write in place. I've seen an exact similar case in a different programming language, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: At the end of your JSON file, we can see that there are two braces. However, only one brace is needed. The other one is unnecessary, hence the error. Try removing it.

Comment: @Fowled i think the issue is that JSON.stringyfy() is writing this to the file.